# How do you present slides (over browser) in Google slides similar to "office presentation service"

Tags: google-slides

I am trying to "present google slides" online.That is, if people only have a browser and a conference line, I give them a link (ahead of time, say over email), they open it and see what I am presenting in google slide. As I advance the slide/animate, their browser also automatically animates/advances to the next slide.

In other words, I am looking for ["Office Presentation Service"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/broadcast-your-powerpoint-presentation-online-to-a-remote-audience-25330108-518e-44be-a281-e3d85f784fee) equivalent for Google Slides. Does it exist?

Just to clarify - I am not looking for "File>Publish to the web"  functionality. The below image is not what I am looking for 
[image]

It is (a) not synchronous between the "presenter" and the remote participant and (b) does not advance on mouse clicks from the presenter

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't exists as a built-in function of Google Slides. One option is to use an online video conference / streaming service (i.e. Google Meet, Skype,  Youtube Live, Zoom, etc.) to share your screen with your audience.

Answer (score -1):

Google Slides has a presentation mode. You can activate it by going to the “View” menu and selecting “Present”.